# How to fix syntax error in basic input function

Tags: python

I'm studying basic computer science using Python; one of our first practice questions involves creating a basic input value that tells you what your letter grade is.

I have some code already made, but the last line of the code doesn't run due to a syntax error. Since I am inexperienced I do not know where the error is.

```
grade = float(input("Enter your grade."))
if grade >= 90:
    print("Your letter grade is an A.")

elif grade >= 80:
    print ("Your letter grade is a B.")

elif grade >= 70:
    print ("Your letter grade is a C.")

elif grade >= 60:
    print ("Your letter grade is a D.")

elif grade >= 50:
    print ("Your letter grade is an E.")

else grade:
    print ("You failed :(")
```

You're supposed to enter any value and the result should be just a message telling you your letter grade but all I find is a syntax error on the last section (else grades)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This raises the question: what do you think the difference between `else` and `elif` is?

Comment: I think, ELIF is a conditional that incorporates every previous option, while ELSE is just every conditional that doesn't satisfy any of the conditions, IF and ELIF combined.

Comment: Then why would `else` require *any* condition?

Comment: ELSE is probably the only command that allows you to "capture" every other option that doesn't have a special condition attached to the values you've entered. Sorry if I'm answering the question wrong, and thanks for these thought-provoking discussions - they are beneficial to new learners like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "grade" after the `else`, so the last two lines read:

```py
else: 
    print("You failed :(")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following change should work.

```
else:
    print ("You failed :(")
```

Bonus tip, when formatting code using markup/writing on stack exchange, use ``` to do multiple lines of code formatting.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: Consider accepting @kates answer (Kate answer first, it seems fair). https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Seems like there is a wait time before you can accept an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting- the more you know!

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement consists of, at a minimum, two parts: a condition to evaluate, and a block of code to execute if that condition is true.

```
if grade >= 90:
    print("Your letter grade is an A.")
```

You can also add an `else` clause, which provides a block of code to execute if the condition is *not* true.

```
if grade >= 90:
    print("Your letter grade is an A.")
else:
    print("Your letter grade is not an A.")
```

That would be sufficient, though it leads to ugly nested code like

```
if grade >= 90:
    print("Your letter grade is an A.")
else:
    if grade >= 80:
        print("Your letter grade is a B.")
    else:
        if grade >= 70:
            print("Your letter grade is a C.")
        else:
            if grade >= 60:
                print("Your letter grade is a D.")
            else:
                print("Your letter grade is an F.")
```

To avoid that, you can also specify 1 or more `elif` clauses, that combine an `else` with an immediately following `if`. (Think, e.g., of contracting `else: if grade >=80` to `elif grade >= 80:`.)
This cuts down on a lot of unnecessary indentation.

```
if grade >= 90:
    print("Your letter grade is an A.")
elif grade >= 80:
    print("Your letter grade is a B.")
elif grade >= 70:
    print("Your letter grade is a C.")
elif grade >= 60:
    print("Your letter grade is a D.")
else:
    print("Your letter grade is an F.")
```

Because this is a collection of statements, not an expression, you don't need an `else` clause at all; you don't *have* to do anything if none of the conditions are true.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very detailed explanation.